# Why do i keep getting error: response status is 400 with POST function in API

Tags: post

I am currently busy creating a web API, but everytime I try to post new data I get an error.
The following picture shows what error I get:

[image: error:response status 400]

The following picture shows the code I used in my customer controller to post new data:

[image: API post code].

I first check if the `dbcontext` I created it empty if not I use the `dbcontect.customer.add(customer)` to add a new object to my customers in db context. Then I used `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` to save changes. I also put in a `DbUpdateException` to insure that the same id is not given to two or more customers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: As for the problem itself... Does control ever enter the `PostCustomer` method, or does the error happen before that?  What is the `Customer` object?  What request is being made to produce the error?  What do these errors tell you about that request?